# Saving an image from pixel data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create a program which will save images from pixel data obtained through openCV canny edge detection. Right now, the program saves a small image file in the correct path but the image file does not contain any of the data from the webcam.

An example of what should be saved in the image file:
[picture of edge detected room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFVj1.jpg)

Versus what is actually saved: [just a black rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbtYo.jpg)

**CODE BELOW:**

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from numpy import asarray

import PIL

from PIL import Image

import cv2


def LiveCamEdgeDetection_canny(image_color):
   
    threshold_1 = 100  #LINES

    threshold_2 = 50    #NOISE

    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    canny = cv2.Canny(image_gray, threshold_1, threshold_2)

    return canny


# Main calling function to initialize webcam and apply edge detection

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()   
    cv2.imshow('Live Edge Detection', LiveCamEdgeDetection_canny(frame))
    #cv2.imshow('Webcam Video', frame)
    #print(LiveCamEdgeDetection_canny(frame))
    
    # Store pixel data
    pixels = [LiveCamEdgeDetection_canny(frame)]
    image_todraw = np.array(pixels)
    image_todraw = np.reshape(image_todraw, (720, 1280))
    image_todraw *= 255
    
    image_tosave = Image.fromarray(image_todraw.astype(np.uint8))
    image_tosave.save('/Users/user/Desktop/destinationFolder/RETRY.jpeg', 'JPEG')
    
    #print(image_tosave)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 'p': #13 Enter Key
        break
        
        
cap.release() # camera release 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I appreciate all the help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `image_todraw *= 255` line.

Below is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Your solution worked.

Comment: If you accept this as a solution, in the future people who have the same problem will benefit this answer. For more detail please see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)